# Razor Pages добавление и присвоение ролей

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc

Я пытаюсь понять, как в Razor Pages 2.1. добавлять роли и присваивать их пользователям. Мне необходимо создать роль администратора и присвоить её предсозданному (seed) пользователю.

Я нашел, как это делается  в MVC [делается в MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42471866/how-to-create-roles-in-asp-net-core-and-assign-them-to-users)  [(вторая статья)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-2.1), но к сожалению, эти подход в Razor Pages у меня не сработали.

Подскажите, как можно создать и присвоить роли в Razor Pages 2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось сделать следующим образом. Сперва, я воспользовался кодом, предложенным пользователем Paul Madson в https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42471866/how-to-create-roles-in-asp-net-core-and-assign-them-to-users. Нижеследующий метод я вставил в файл Startup.cs. Он создает роль администратора и присваивает её предсоздаваемому пользователю.

```
    private void CreateRoles(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var roleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        var userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        Task<IdentityResult> roleResult;
        string email = "someone@somewhere.com";

        //Check that there is an Administrator role and create if not
        Task<bool> hasAdminRole = roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Administrator");
        hasAdminRole.Wait();

        if (!hasAdminRole.Result)
        {
            roleResult = roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Administrator"));
            roleResult.Wait();
        }

        //Check if the admin user exists and create it if not
        //Add to the Administrator role

        Task<ApplicationUser> testUser = userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
        testUser.Wait();

        if (testUser.Result == null)
        {
            ApplicationUser administrator = new ApplicationUser
            {
            Email = email,
            UserName = email,
            Name = email
            };

            Task<IdentityResult> newUser = userManager.CreateAsync(administrator, "_AStrongP@ssword!123");
            newUser.Wait();

            if (newUser.Result.Succeeded)
            {
                Task<IdentityResult> newUserRole = userManager.AddToRoleAsync(administrator, "Administrator");
                newUserRole.Wait();
            }
        }

    }
```

Затем, в этом же файле в методе Configure я добавил аргумент IServiceProvider serviceProvider, то есть по части сигнатуры он стал выглядеть наподобие Configure(..., IServiceProvider serviceProvider). В нем же, в самом конце, я добавил строку CreateRoles(serviceProvider). Чтобы этот код работал, предварительно следует создать, например, в папке Data. следующий класс:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sobopedia.Data
{
    public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Наконец, в методе ConfigureServices следует заменить

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SobopediaContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

на

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SobopediaContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

В результате, после запуска программы в таблице AspNetRoles у вас появится новая роль, а в таблице AspNetUsers новый пользователь, обладающий этой ролью.

К сожалению, если вы создавали шаблон с изначальной авторизацией, то при добавлении

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SobopediaContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

перестанут работать страницы Login и Registration. Чтобы исправить это, необходимо:

1. Scaffold Identity следуя (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio). Если вы используете шаблон с предсозданной авторизацией, то смотрите раздел Scaffold identity into a Razor project with authorization.
2. После создания шаблона следует заменить **во всем решении** все IdentityUser на ApplicationUser. За исключением класса ApplicationUser, который по прежнему должен наследовать IdentityUser.
3. Убрать из Areas/identity/Pages/Account/Register.cs (то есть модели) все, что связано с EmailSernder, если у вас нет его имплементации.

Чтобы проверить корректность работы данного решения можно сделать следующее. В конце метода ConfigureServices в классе Startup.cs добавляем следующее:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("RequireAdministratorRole", policy => policy.RequireRole("Administrator"));
            });

    services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
                {
options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Contact","RequireAdministratorRole");
                }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

Также, для надежности или если этот код не сработает, в модель страницы Contact можно добавить [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")], чтобы она выглядели следующим образом:

```
namespace Sobopedia.Pages
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    public class ContactModel : PageModel
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            Message = "Your contact page.";
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь, попасть на страницу Contact вы сможете только при условии, что авторизуетесь с логином someone@somewhere.com и паролем _AStrongP@ssword!123. Метод может не сработать, если при создании администратора будет использован пароль, содержащий запрещенные и не содержащий необходимые символы.